# Is there a puppet cheat sheet out there?

Tags: puppet

I'm looking for a short document that set out a list of the different types of resource defined by puppet with maybe a line or two of description for each. A similar layout for attributes would also be of interest.

BTW, I've found [these docs](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/types/) and am looking for something more concise.

Comment: The puppet type reference is basically the best document for this.
Yes, it's long, and somewhat overwhelming at first. You probably won't find something much shorter which is also complete. I approach the document differently: I decide what I want to do, then look for the puppet type which will deal with it.

Comment: @Avleen: I'm looking for more of an "at a glance" kind of reference rather than a complete reference. I want something I can use to quickly find the name of the thing I'm looking for, so I can then go and do a more in depth search for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make one yourself on the fly (2.6.x syntax)

`puppet doc -r type` -- generates type reference

`puppet doc -r function` -- generates function reference

etc.

That way it's easily grep-able and accurately reflects the version you have installed.

Comment: OTOH, it's kind of hard to pin on a wall.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>There isn't one. But there's going to be soon!</strike>

<strike>A draft of the text is at http://projects.puppetlabs.com/projects/puppet/wiki/Core_Types_Cheat_Sheet; is there anything missing from there that you'd like to see added? (Keeping in mind that there'll likely be a second cheat sheet with a rough guide to the language syntax; this is only about the core resource types.)</strike>

<strike>(Also, there's a proof-of-concept double-sided PDF available over at the [issue ticket about this](http://projects.puppetlabs.com/issues/5249).)</strike>

[Yes, there is!](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/#drive-thru)

Comment: Looks good. Btu just the type name and the first bit of each description is the kind of things I was thinking of. As a web page it could work to have that, and then hide the rest of the text as a collapsed section.

Comment: Sounds like you could get some mileage out of `puppet describe -s file`. The -s switch makes it spit out a naked list of the attributes for that type, if all you need is a memory jog.